# What do the square brackets in function syntax mean on MDN?

Tags: javascript

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) uses:

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])
```

instead of just this:

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
```

What do the square brackets mean?

Comment: It means that those are _optional_ parameters

Comment: Why is noone saying the most important ? [ ] means 0 or 1, { } means 0 to N.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a conventional way in technical documentation of saying that part is *optional*.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other common conventions I should be aware of when reading technical documentations?

Comment: Backus-Naur form (BNF) and EBNF are common grammar forms, used to describe the syntax of computer languages. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Comment: @Saravana I can't think of other popular conventions on JS documentations right now. Some languages hold more conventions, but as far as I recall `[]` are most commonly used for *optional segments*.